# Why the Java enum constants initialization is not complete?

Tags: java, enums

I stumbled upon a very weird bug and I can't explain why it happens. Imagine the following enum:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MyEnum.CONSTANT1.get());
        System.out.println(MyEnum.CONSTANT2.get());
    }

    private enum MyEnum {
        CONSTANT1(staticMethod1()),
        CONSTANT2(staticMethod2());

        private static final Color WHY_AM_I_NULL = new Color(255, 255, 255);

        private final Color color;

        private MyEnum(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Color get() {
            return color;
        }

        private static Color staticMethod1() {
            return new Color(100, 100, 100);
        }

        private static Color staticMethod2() {
            return WHY_AM_I_NULL;
        }
    }

}
```

The results when you run this are:

```
java.awt.Color[r=100,g=100,b=100]
null
```

The question is, why the second one is null?

**Ammendment:** 
If you put the WHY_AM_I_NULL in a private static class inside the enum, then it is initialized first.

Comment: Ammended new observation

Comment: Also, if you try to use the constant directly, not through a method, Eclipse shows an error. That's not the case when using the static method. Even FindBugs doesn't show a problem! I think this deserves a warning at least

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that all static fields (and enum instances count as such) are initialized in their declared order ([specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.2)). So when `CONSTANT2` is instantiated, the field `WHY_AM_I_NULL` is still not initialized (and therefore `null`).

As you can't put the field before the enum instances, you have to find some other way of doing what you want (e.g., putting the field outside the enum class). If you tell us, what you really want to accomplish, one could make further suggestions.

**Edit:** If you put `WHY_AM_I_NULL` in a nested class, the fields of this class will be initialized as soon as the class is first accessed (i.e., in this case during the execution of `staticMethod2`).

Comment: I just want to have a constant, that is used in the enum constant's initialization. It worked when I put the constant in a private static class inside the enum.

The users of this Enum don't care about this inner constant and I don't want to have it declared more than once (or created more than once if you have it as a method that creates the color)

Comment: In this case I would indeed use a static nested class as field-holder class.

Answer (score 4):

Enums are the compiler feature. Actually compiler creates class named MyEnum that contains 2 public static fields CONSTANT1 and CONSTANT2 and other code.

Static initialization is done up-to-down, so the CONSTANT2 is created and is initialized before static variable WHY_AM_I_NULL. This is why WHY_AM_I_NULL is null when CONSTANT2 is being initialized.

Answer (score 2):

`WHY_AM_I_NULL` is null when *staticMethod2* is invoked - this is how [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) specifies initialization

In a different sequence you'd get `100, 255` instead of `100, null`:

```
private static final Color WHY_AM_I_NULL = new Color(255, 255, 255);
private enum MyEnum {
    CONSTANT1(staticMethod1()),
    CONSTANT2(staticMethod2());
    //...
```

Comment: -1. It doesn't even answer why a field is not initialized inside enum instead diverting the issue by showing how it works outside of enum. Another point to note that **it's never a correct answer to write "It happens because that's how it was specified."** See [How to Answer](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the static fields (including enum values) are initialized in the order they appear in the file.

So `CONSTANT1`, and `CONSTANT2` get initialized before `WHY_AM_I_NULL`, therefore `CONSTANT2` is initialized with `null`.