# Enum.valueOf bug with JDK 7 SE where .values() gets corrupted

Tags: java, enums, java-7

This seems like a crazy error, but `Enum.valueOf(type, name)` seems to be unstable on Oracle JDK 7 SE.

The manifestation is that, on the exact same name String (I've verified this), the call to `valueOf()` sometimes throws `IllegalArgumentException` with the message `No enum constant ...`.

My team ran this through the Eclipse debugger, and what we noticed is that in the following JDK implementation of valueOf on enum, `enumConstantDirectory()`, i.e. the `values()` list for an enum, sometimes seem to be missing some values. Not the entirety of all the values defined in the enum itself.

I can work around the bug by calling `Enum.valueOf(enumclass.class, "XXX")` for all possible enum values on JVM startup. When I do this, it seems `values()` always contains the full set.

However, if I don't do this type of initialization, sometimes `Enum.valueOf()` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Context: I'm seeing this problem when using XStream 1.4.4 to convert POJO objects that convert enum, but the problem doesn't seem to be inherently with XStream.

Has anyone seen this kind of error?  I would love to hear about it if you have.
It boggles my mind.  Is this a bug in the Oracle JDK/JVM implementation?

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType,
                                            String name) {
    T result = enumType.enumConstantDirectory().get(name);
    if (result != null)
        return result;
    if (name == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Name is null");
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "No enum constant " + enumType.getCanonicalName() + "." + name);
}
```

Other relevant details:

We are using the `org.reflections` library to scan all enums in our code at startup. During the scanning, we take the type of the enum, and call `clazz.getEnumConstants()` on the Class object associated with the enum. This might be a relevant detail.

In looking and the `java.lang.Class.getEnumConstants()` implementation, it seems to share the same `enumConstants` shared object within the Class. I wonder if there's a problem with the implementation here.

Our enum is pretty simple, no static initialization, etc.

```
public enum ScreeningRuleType
{
  INSERT,
  CONFIRMATION,
  AMOUNT,
  EXISTENCE,
  BAN,
  SELECTION,
  CUSTOM; 

  private long id;
  private String descr;

  ScreeningRuleType()
  {
    id = this.ordinal();
    descr= this.toString().replace("_", " ");
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
In experimenting with this, I'm finding another manifestation.  After using the System.out initialization, now instead of throwing IllegalArgumentException, the value returned by Enum.valueOf seems to be random.

This shows what I'm seeing in the Eclipse debugger.  It clearly shows I'm calling valueOf() on the string "EXISTENCE" and "EXISTENCE".intern(), and clearly shows it's returning AMOUNT() instead.

[image: Debugger expression]

Comment: Sometimes implies intermittent failure; is there any noticeable pattern? How often does it fail?

Comment: Is it possible that the string you're sending through could contain embedded nulls? If that's the case, it might not be picking up the correct constant.

Comment: It fails only for some of our enums, and only through some code paths, but it is reproducible in that code path.   By simply adding a line of code to System.out.println(Enum.valueOf(type, "xxx")) at the start of the unit test, the error goes away.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.toCharArray()))`, where `str` is the value you're passing to `Enum.valueOf`. Look for anomalies.

Comment: If adding something as benign as a `System.out.println` is causing it to work, could it be some sort of concurrency issue?

Comment: @user2337324 How is the string that is passed into `valueOf` constructed?

Comment: @Telthien Yes, we've done str.toCharArray() and str.toByteArray() and validated that the str is the exact same.  We've even passed the reconstructed String from both the char[] and byte[], with the same erroneous results.   The Strings are definitely the same.

Comment: @user2337324 Does `equals` return `true` on those strings?

Comment: @Vivin Paliath String is not constructed.  It's basically just "XXX" in the code.  However, I've tried new String(byte[]), new String(char[]), "xxx".intern(), and they all produce the same result.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath Yes, it's not a string problem.  I understand the concept of String pool in Java, and have tested with .intern() to eliminate that possibility.  I've debugged Enum.valueOf() method in the JDK, and it seems the list of values() for that enum is sometimes missing some values.   That is the cause of the IllegalArgumentException.  (it's not that the String didn't match, it's that the String isn't in the values() array for the enum)

Comment: @user2337324 That is quite odd. I think this might be a symptom of some other problem. Is there a lot of concurrency going on around this?

Comment: @user2337324 Copy the enum and the associated code out into its own isolated project. Also, print out all the `Enum.values()` strings. Also, check concurrency.

Comment: There is some concurrency in the app start up.  I'm using pax.exam junit test runner due to our dependency on WeldSE (though I don't believe this is a Weld problem, because the errors are not with Injected classes).  When I have some time I can try to isolate this into a reasonably small test case.  Our app has a good amount of dependencies.

Comment: Can you provide a SSCCE? I'm using MyEnum.values() a lot and never had any issues...

Comment: Also don't trust the debugger if you're seeing strange effects while debugging. Sometimes you just see an internal state which might mean nothing.

Comment: @Puce This isn't just happening in the debugger.  It fails on cmdline via mvn/surefire, fails on Jenkins, etc.

Comment: @Puce yeah, I'd like an SSCCE as well ;-). It might take a while, considering it seems to be initialization codepath depdenent. I've been using enums since JDK 1.5, and this is the first time I've run into any issues with it.

Comment: When i have some time I might try JRockit or IBM Java SDK to see if I get the same behavior. If it works in either of those, then this gets interesting...

Comment: If you think you've found a bug, please check if it has been reported already and if it hasn't please file an issue: http://bugs.sun.com/ (still sun domain?! ;-) )

Comment: could it be a class loading problem? i.e. some old class file with fewer enum fields is loaded sometimes. try a clean build.

Comment: Actually we found the issue.  It's a face + palm moment.  We corrupted the enum via reflection API's by attempting a deep (nonshallow) copy of a class containing an enum.  This had the effect of wiping out all instance variables of the singleton enum itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually we found the issue.  It's a face + palm moment.  We corrupted the enum via reflection API's by attempting a deep (nonshallow) copy of a class containing an enum.  This had the effect of wiping out all instance variables of the singleton enum itself.  Thanks for all the assistance and suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

I forget where I came across something similar - I suspect however that it was pre-java 7 and may have been back in the Java 4/5 days.

The issue is that the constructing of the accompanying structures that go with the `enum` is only triggered the first time one of the `enum`s is accessed. Unfortunately, if you call one of the methods that rely on these structures, `valueOf` or `EnumSet.allOf` for example **before** accessing one of the `enum`s it generally fails catastrophically.

Sadly I refactored the code so this would not happen so I no longer have the sample to hand. I will try to reproduce the issue and get back to you.

I see here - [Why the Java enum constants initialization is not complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7188358/823393) another occurrence of the issue with a demonstration.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a cyclic dependency within an static initialiser. / Kind of lucky it doesn't deadlock. Well, it might well do occasionally under certain conditions.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, that's a very nice piece of information! I imagine it's one of those things that you don't recognize or realize until you run into it.

Comment: This does look like a static initialization ordering issue, but it's not quite the same example as what we are doing.  In our case,  MyEnum.values() per your example would be missing one of the values, not have an unintialized value2.